# Lookup Printers Available to User on Remote Desktop Session (WMI)

Tags: printing, vb6, printers

We have an old system that takes ages to print because VB6 is looping through every available printer till it finds the right printer to print to.
`For Each xx In Printers`

The problem is that the Printers object is pulling though tons of printers and slowing the program down significantly. **I've tried using WMI but don't know if it's possible to pass a printer object back.** It crashes at the line `CollectPrinters = objPrinter`.

```
Public Function CollectPrinters(ByVal PrinterToUse As String) As Printer

  Dim strComputer As String
  Dim objWMIService As Object
  Dim strPrinterList As String

  strComputer = "."
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

  Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer WHERE Local = True AND DeviceID LIKE 'client preview%'")

  For Each objPrinter In colInstalledPrinters
    Debug.Print objPrinter.NAME
    strPrinterList = strPrinterList + objPrinter.NAME & vbCrLf
    If objPrinter.NAME = PrinterToUse Then
        'CollectPrinters = objPrinter
        Exit Function
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

If I'm barking up the wrong tree, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: In my accounting app, I just cycle through the system printers collection and put them in a combobox, and allow my users, by user, to select which printer they want for each function - invoices, checks, statements, etc.  Is this something you're having to prompt on a regular basis instead of having an option to pre-select printer(s)?

Comment: "it crashes" but what specifically is the error?

Comment: I imagine it would be "Type Mismatch", because I can't see why objPrinter would be of type "Printer".

Comment: I have to admit that I am confused about why iterating through "Printers" would be so slow. Can you give a code example of how you use this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the comments, I have figured out a workaround. The server has tons of users and printers, the Printers object picks up every printer and not just the current printer. We also use a product called ThinPrint which outputs a preview to the users PC. The workaround basically only runs the `For Each xx In Printers` if the default printer isn't ThinPrint. In most instances, ThinPrint is the default so the performance gains are great.